# Creating a delegate using a Class doesn't work if the delegate contains a "out" argument

Tags: c#, delegates, outlook-addin, factory

I'm creating an Outlook addins, and for some events, the library need to be connected to some delegated function.

I need the following:

```
public delegate void ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(out bool Cancel)
public delegate void ItemEvents_10_AttachmentAddEventHandler(Attachment Attachment)
```

In order to provide those function, I created a class that can generate those function :

```
public class MyHandlers
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

    public MyHandlers(Outlook.MailItem mMailItem)
    {
        mailItem = mMailItem;
    }

    public void Handle_Open(out bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = false;
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public void Handle_Add_Attachment(Attachment Attachment)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

And I use the factory like this :

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook::MailItem;
MyHandlers mh = MyHandlers(mailItem);
mailItem.Open += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(mh.Handle_Open);
mailItem.AttachmentAdd += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_AttachmentAddEventHandler(mh.Handle_Add_Attachment);
```

For `ItemEvents_10_AttachmentAddEventHandler` it's working fine.

For `ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler` I have the following error: 
`No overload for 'Handle_Open' matches delegate 'ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler'`.

The only difference between the two signatures is the "out" keyword.

The signature seems fine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_openeventhandler.aspx), and if I don't use the "Class Factory" trick, it's working fine (but I need this trick in order to keep track of `mailItem`).

What did I miss ?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you working with? When I add a COM reference on my machine and look at `ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler`, its `Cancel` parameter is marked `ref`, rather than `out`. (Outlook 2016). If I change `Handle_Open` to match that (and switch what appears to be `C++/<something MS>` to C# for the factory method) it compiles just fine.

Comment: Awesome ! I'm still a noob in C#, did't know the difference between `ref` and `out` !